# Removing item from recyclerView after data update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am updating data from a recyclerview inside the adapter:

```
 private void desmarcar_anuncio_favorito(final String anuncioF, final String usuarioF, final Integer position) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";



        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_MEDIA_ANUNCIO, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                String ultimo = response;
                String ya = "borrado";
                if (ultimo.equals(ya)){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Anuncio eliminado de favoritos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateData(anuncios);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Error al eliminar anuncio de favoritos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("anuncio", anuncioF);
                params.put("usuario", usuarioF);





                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }



public void updateData(List data) {
        this.anuncios = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Using this code, the update is done in the remote database, but the recyclerview item is not updated, in this case it should be removed from the recyclerview.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateData(anuncios);
```

You are updating the recyclerview with the current value of the data `anuncios`, you have to remove the item from the list anuncios `anuncios.remove(indexOfItemRemoving)` then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRemoved(indexOfItemRemoving)`

What you need to do is get the `indexOfItemRemoving` to update.

Your method updateData replaces the list in your case, with the same list as before, you need to change the list and notify the adapter only.

Something like:

```
    if (ultimo.equals(ya)){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Anuncio eliminado de favoritos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int indexOfItemRemoving = anuncios.size(); // get the correct item here instead
        anuncios.remove(indexOfItemRemoving);
        notifyItemRemoved(indexOfItemRemoving);
    }
```

Theres an advantage using notifyItemInserted/Removed/RangeChanged cause RecyclerView handle those events with nice events animations feedbacks

Comment: I need to change indexOfItemRemoving with the item position I need to remove?

Comment: exactly, then the code i posted will work without need to use updateData

Comment: I don´t understand the line int indexOfItemRemoving = anuncios.size();

Comment: replace it with ```int indexOfItemRemoving = position;```